# Why boolean is not working on str?

Tags: python, boolean

While trying to learn Python with the online course at university of waterloo [link here](https://open.cs.uwaterloo.ca/python-from-scratch/5/5/#5) the rest follows:

I am trying to write a function which will consume a string, and if the first letter is equal to 'y' or 'Y', it will have a "True" boolean return. Else, it will be have a "False" output. This is my code:

```
def is_yes(x):
    if (x[0] == 'Y' or 'y'):
        return True
    else:
        return False

is_yes('yes')
```

The function has no errors and the only output is: `[Finished in 0.1s]`

while testing the code with adding a `print()` to the function call: `print(is_yes('yes'))` , no matter what the input, the answer is always True.

what is wrong with the code? Also, I'm trying to self-learn and there is no one to teach me, so I Hope I do not get banned because I ask stupid questions, I am just trying to learn.

Comment: or 'y'. 'y' is always evaluated true!

Comment: @sascha removed the brackets, still always True

Comment: Yeah my bad. The or 'y' is the problem!

Comment: @sascha Woaa... Thats so weird. but it Works now. Thanks!

Comment: It's not weird and the reason is probably explained in the duplicate-question.

Comment: @sascha yes, I just read it and it all makes sense now :) Thanks everyone!

Comment: also instead of the (if , else) statement, it is better practice and less redundant to simply do a "return (x[0] == 'Y' or x[0] == 'y')"

Comment: @NeelSampemane excuse my ignorance, but is it better practice because less lines take less memory?